# html5 canvas is not hardware accelerated in android 4.4

Tags: android, html5-canvas

I have made a small html5 game which runs perfectly in ICS and Jelly Bean. But, after upgrade to android 4.4 (latest 4.4.2), html5 canvas performance is extremely poor.

There are couple of issues raised like this 
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=315111

I couldn't find any stackoverflow post regarding this. Can anyone post any workaround/hack to overcome this issue?

Comment: looks like everyone is affected : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27040512 (please see the performance issue row)

Answer (score 0):

Try [CrossWalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/), it's Chrome Run-time packaged for use in Android and other platforms.

#### Advantages

- Supports Cordova API
- Supports WebGl out of the Box
- Vastly improves performance in Canvas
- Easy, familiar Interface
- Can build shared HTML5 Apps

#### Disadvantages

- Increase App size drastically